# Can we use google cloud SQL with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-cloud-sql

I am developing a dynamic web project which uses SQL for storing data and Spring MVC java for server side.I have deployed my war in elastic beanstalk running on apache tomcat server environment.My doubt can I link Cloud SQL with Amazon AWS for free.If possible then how to configure Amazon and java project to access google cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could configure [external access to the Google's Cloud SQL] (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app), however I don't think it's the best idea.

Using the beanstalk you may rather deploy a rds database. it will cost you almost the same. The access is much faster and you wouldn't need to co sider networking charges

Comment: Thanks for swift response.Is RDS and elastic beanstalk comes under one year free tier policy.if so is it enough to update my application properties file and rebuild war to access database.

Comment: how much gb we can use per month

Comment: 12 months after signup you can use ec2 (beanstalk) and rds with micro instances https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Thanks for swift response.Isit enough to configure my project application properties where I provide jdbc datasource to hit rd instance and rebuild war and deploy.will it work

Comment: @VenkatRaman it depends on your application, you should know what you need to change.. However be aware - if you provision RDS along with your beanstalk deployment, it will be deprovisioned (deleted) when you delete your application (loosing all data). If you provision RDS aside before the beanstalk deployment, you will retain your data.